# How can I specify an icon with a RELATIVE path for a Linux desktop entry file?

Tags: linux, desktop, shortcut

For one of my Linux applications, I have the application binary, a launcher.sh script (for the LD_LIBRARY_PATH) and a .desktop file, all in the same folder.

I'd like to use a relative path rather than an absolute path for the icon.

I've tried:

```
Icon=app.svg
Icon=./app.svg
Icon=$PWD/app.svg
Icon=$(dirname %k)/app.svg
```

but none of these work (only `Icon=/path/to/app.svg`). If it's not possible to specify a relative path and I must use a workaround, I was thinking I could regenerate the icon path in the .desktop file every time the launcher.sh script is run.

What would be the best way to do that? Using `sed` or some other replacement utility with a pseudo-regex like `Icon=([valid path chars]+)\n` perhaps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After doing some more research it doesn't look like it's possible to specify relative paths for an icon in a desktop entry file as far as I can see.

The workaround I used was to add the following code to the end of my launcher.sh script:

```
mv myapp.desktop myapp.desktop-bak
sed -e "s,Icon=.*,Icon=$PWD/app.svg,g" myapp.desktop-bak > myapp.desktop
rm myapp.desktop-bak
```

This will update the path of the icon each time the launcher script is run, and since the .desktop file points to the launcher script, clicking the .desktop file effectively updates its icon.

I know you could use `cat` or the -i option to shorten the above code but I've read that the solution I used is more reliable. If anyone has further information on that please do post a comment.

Comment: Thanks for this ... still though, that's a sucky spec.

Comment: Sure is... I can't believe no one thought of adding relative path support (apparently).

Comment: Well, I read somewhere else that it was a security concern: what if you moved the .desktop file, and accidentally opened a different executable than the one you thought ... and I guess that's a fair point. But then another method to specify icons would've been nice.

Comment: This should work great with this question/answer http://askubuntu.com/a/345123/112263

Comment: Wouldn't that still be broken until its run once? So its just broken cause it can't latch itself into a working state... I guess your only patching the icon path and not the exec path though

Comment: I can't believe all these work-arounds just to get an icon work. And indeed it does not even work until you run the desktop file for the first time. Things like these prevent Linux dominating on desktops.

Answer (score 5):

It's true that the [FreeDesktop specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys)
does not permit relative paths:

> **Standard Keys**
>
> `Icon`
>
> Icon to display in file manager, menus, etc. If the name is an absolute path,
> the given file will be used. If the name is not an absolute path, the
> algorithm described in the [Icon Theme
> Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Standards/icon-theme-spec) will be
> used to locate the icon.
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> Values of type `iconstring` are the names of icons; these may be absolute
> paths, or symbolic names for icons located using the algorithm described in
> the [Icon Theme
> Specification](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Standards/icon-theme-spec). Such
> values are not user-displayable, and are encoded in UTF-8.

The workaround is adequate,
although it probably won't work for menus and panel launchers.
But if you're comfortable patching the desktop file
when running the `launcher.sh` script,
why not actually install the icon?
You can do it in two lines:

```
cp app.svg ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/
cp app.svg ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
```

and then put

```
Icon=app
```

in the desktop file (`app` is just the filename without a file extension).

This is the intended mechanism for locating icons
that don't have an absolute path,
and will ensure the icons show up in menus and custom launchers.
The [spec has this to say](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/latest/ar01s07.html):

> So, you're an application author, and want to install application
> icons so that they work in the KDE and Gnome menus. Minimally you
> should install a 48x48 icon in the hicolor theme. This means
> installing a PNG file in $prefix/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps.
> Optionally you can install icons in different sizes. For example,
> installing a svg icon in $prefix/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps
> means most desktops will have one icon that works for all sizes.

One way this can be done
is with the `xdg-icon-resource` command, e.g.

```
$ xdg-icon-resource install --novendor --context apps --size 48 example-app.png
```

However, `xdg-icon-resource`
[does not support SVG images](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/issues/82),
and in practice this accomplishes the same thing:

```
$ cp example-app.svg ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/
$ cp example-app.svg ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
```

(That's not a typo: put the SVG file in the `48x48/apps` folder
and the menus and panels will be perfectly happy.)

For menus, it's a good idea to update the icon cache after installing.

```
$ update-icon-caches ~/.local/share/icons
```

Then you can simply give the `iconstring` as `example-app` like this:

```
Icon=example-app
```

This is not a relative path,
but it solves the problem of having to use an absolute path
and won't break if the desktop file is moved to a different location.

For what it's worth,
support for relative paths
was discussed on the FreeDesktop mailing list
back in September 2008:

> Magnus Bergmark magnus.bergmark at gmail.com
>
> Tue Sep 23 01:01:32 PDT 2008
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> I propose that we allow the usage of relative paths in some way also.
>
> *Use-cases*
>
> 1. I use a lot of .directory files to make directories containing a movie
>    have the movie poster as the icon. This behaviour could apply to any form of
>    media, like comic books, music (album art) and photos.
> 2. A vendor might want to bundle an icon to a piece of software they're
>    distributing to go with a .desktop file which are not to go in the
>    desktop menu and therefore are still located in the application directory.

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2008-September/009940.html

The only counterargument I was able to find
to this proposal is here:

> A .desktop file
> that is not intended to go into a standard applications directory is
> almost entirely useless. Perhaps you should look at some of the
> software bundle proposals and implementations, and work with using
> those, instead. Another option is the xdg utils scripts, to install
> the .desktop file and icons in the appropriate places. I can only
> presume that your uninstalled application also intends to not follow
> the Icon Theme and Icon Naming specifications either. And I don't see
> setting the directory's icon as useful really. Setting an icon for the
> actual executable would be much more useful, though elf binaries do
> not have resources like win32 binaries do.

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2008-September/009962.html

Related questions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/277190/how-to-package-an-application-icon-properly
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404955/is-there-a-home-directory-location-for-overriding-icons
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428992/why-do-freedesktop-desktop-files-not-allow-relative-paths
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585997/assign-an-icon-to-a-custom-mimetype

Relevant links:

- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/issues/82
- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68507
- https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73463
- https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2008-September/009940.html
- https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2011-April/011883.html
- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use `echo $(echo ~)` to use command output or `echo $(echo $var)` for variables

**For example:**

```bash
echo "Icon=$(echo ~)/Pictures/Icons/whatsapp-webapp.svg" > path/to/file.desktop
```

If you are interested in multi line echo command check out [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77277/how-to-append-multiple-lines-to-a-file)