# desktop application with gnome-terminal: relative paths to script and icon

Tags: bash, ubuntu, icons, desktop-application, launcher

I am using `gnome-terminal` to create a clickable desktop application. The application should be downloaded in a zip folder, with a sub-directory `bin` containing my `myapp.desktop`.
I would like to have a different directory `somedir` in my zip file containing main application script and the icon for the application.

However, `gnome-terminal` does not seem to work with relative paths. Here my `myapp.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c -i 'exec $SHELL --init-file ../somedir/myscript.sh'"
Icon=../somedir/myicon.gif
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

My question is: how can I pass the directory from which the application icon was clicked to `gnome-desktop`? Or how can I organize my directory such that I do not have to have `myicon.gif` and `myscript.sh` in the same directory as `myapp.desktop`?

I am aware of the `--working-directory` argument to `gnome-terminal` and tried to pass `$PWD`, without success.

**EDIT:**

Related question: 
 [Desktop Launcher for Python Script Starts Program in Wrong Path (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538023/desktop-launcher-for-python-script-starts-program-in-wrong-path-linux)

A path can be specified in the `.desktop` file, but again, it does not seem to deal with relative paths. If I add
`Path=.`, it is not found.

Comment: This isn't a gnome-terminal question. This is a `.desktop` launcher question. The question is what information about the `.desktop` file being launched does the launcher provide to the spawned process and what does it make available as variables/etc. for use **in** the `.desktop` file. I'm going to guess that the answer is not much that is of use to you for this.

Comment: For the icon, I agree, it is a `.desktop` launcher issue. But event if I execute the `gnome-terminal` command above without launcher, it only finds my `--init-file` `myscript.sh` if it is either in the same directory as my `myapp.desktop` or if I give an absolute path.

Comment: Calling a shell with an init file e.g. `bash --init-file ../somedir/myscript.sh` works well, but does not seem to work correctly with the paths in `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Paths are relative to the working directory of whatever uses them. When you say `myscript.sh` that will look for `myscript.sh` in the *current working directory* of whatever process tries to use that path. I have no idea what working directory the launcher is going to use when it executes your `gnome-terminal` process. It might use the location of the `.desktop` file. It might use your home directory. It might use `/`. Or it might use anything else for that matter.

Comment: Yes, I think the path is relative to my home directory, which is not what I want... In OSX, it worked for me to call `cd -- "$(dirname "$0")"` in my clickable bash script, but I haven't gotten it to work with the launcher in ubuntu .yet

Comment: Your approach seems backwards.  There are very good reasons paths are standardized and there are good reasons why all popular distros have package management systems.  Package your tool according to the standard for your target audience(s) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Based on this [document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) 
and other answers on ask ubuntu (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47775/how-can-i-set-the-path-variable-in-a-desktop-file-to-be-relative-to-the-locat)), I think that you cannot use relative paths directly in the desktop application.

You can however keep your files in the desired folders and include in the package a configuration script that copy the executable and the icon in the default paths, as specified in the documentation ($PATH for the executable and /usr/share/pixmaps for the icon).

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452746/how-can-i-specify-an-icon-with-a-relative-path-for-a-linux-desktop-entry-file) there is a nice workaround. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811032/using-relative-paths-for-gnome-launcher) a solution like the one I proposed.

Everyone seems to agree that it is not possible to use relative paths but ...

... searching a little bit more it seems that there is the possibility to use the home directory as the starting point for the relative path by leave out the forward slash on the path. Based on this page ([link](http://www.gearhack.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Computer/Linux/Relative_Path_with_Linux_.desktop_Files)) this:

```
  Exec="${HOME}/bin/scripts/UNIX/Prototype.bash"
  Path=${HOME}/bin/scripts/UNIX
```

doesn't work

But this:

```
  Exec="Prototype.bash"
  Path=bin/scripts/UNIX
```

should.

Comment: There are probably situations where the environment where the launcher runs is not in your home directory, but as a quick and dirty hack, this holds some promise.

Answer (score 2):

This method does not work because $PWD inside .desktop file, point to home directory.So you should create an installation script to generate "myapp.desktop" and copy both of "myapp.desktop" and "icon.png" to specific directory. copy this script to root of your app and run it!

install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

home_local=$HOME/.local/share
icon_dir=$home_local/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps

myapp_desktop=$home_local/applications/myapp.desktop
myapp_dir=$PWD
myapp=$myapp_dir/bin/myapp.sh
myapp_icons=$myapp_dir/icons/myapp.png

echo "[Desktop Entry]" > $myapp_desktop
echo "Name=MyApp" >> $myapp_desktop
echo "Exec=bash -c 'cd $myapp_dir;bash $myapp;exec bash'" >> $myapp_desktop
echo "Icon=myapp.png" >> $myapp_desktop
echo "Terminal=true" >> $myapp_desktop
echo "Type=Application" >> $myapp_desktop

cp $myapp_icon $icons_dir
```

Comment: both yours and @terence hill's solution look very promising, cannot test it over the holidays though because I don;t have an ubuntu machine (with X)

Answer (score 1):

Make that Exec like look like this:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c -i 'set > /tmp/env_vars.log'"
```

Then check on the log file the available variables (e.g. where it is running from), and adjust your relative path accordingly. If there isn't anything usefull, maybe use dirname on some existing variable to derive the full path, etc.

You can also run like:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c -i 'pwd' > /tmp/curdir.log"
```

And use the path found in curdir.log as the one to be relative to.

Comment: Where do I find the information from where the script was launched in the logfile? I searched for 'launcher' and 'gnome-terminal', but could not find anything.

Comment: The log only contains the precise output that your command generates.  The `set` command simply prints your environment, which however under Bash includes the value of `PWD`.  You could include `date`, `pwd`, and other commands in the log to make it more useful. However, this is not robust against multiple simultaneous instances being started in rapid succession.

Comment: This does not work, `$PWD` at this moment is my home directory and not the directory in which I started the launcher...